# How to add multiple sourcepath to a doclet on windows?

Tags: java, doclet

I created a doclet, it will scan two projects(project A depend on project B)
So I have to add two sourcepath.

Based on doclet docs, I have to use colon to separate multiple source folder: Colon-separated list of source-file directories, like this:

```
String sourcePath = "C:/projA/src/main/java/:C:/projB/src/main/java/";
```

But you can see my testing environment is on windows, the path has something like "c:", so this doesn't work.

I tried to use semi-colon, doesn't work.
If I used one sourcepth, it works perfectly:

```
String sourcePath = "C:/projA/src/main/java/";
String[] myArgs = { "-doclet", MyDoclet.class.getName(), 
            "-sourcepath", sourcePath, "-subpackages", subpackages };
com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(myArgs);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about doclets, but normally paths are separated by a semicolon, and not a colon.

Comment: @notyou, I tried semi-colon, doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, semi-colon works:  pathA;pathB